# Extend forms in symfony2 and 3

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I want to create a new form type that can be used in symfony2 and symfony3. The problem is that it extend entity form type and I can't find a common way of create the getParent() function, since in symfony2 is like:

```
public function getParent()
{
   return 'entity';
}
```

and in symfony3:

```
public function getParent()
{
   return EntityType::class;
}
```

There is any way of do it in a common way, or I need to create two differents form types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `getBlockPrefix()` method in the `AbstractType` class does exist which was introduced in Symfony 2.8:

```
if (method_exists('Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType', 'getBlockPrefix')) {
    return EntityType::class;
} else {
    return 'entity';
}
```

Comment: I see your point in the comment to @igor-pantovic, but your solution don't work.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error?

Comment: My mistake, after research a little, find that your solution work for an old and extensive used bundle https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle/blob/master/Form/Extension/FormFlowFormExtension.php .  Then I review my code and find my mistake. Thanks

Comment: In addition to changing here, I had to change my `services.yml` definition for the extension to reference the the full class name: 
`tags:
   - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EntityType }`

Answer (score 1):

You could read version from kernel, and return parent appropriately:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;

public function getParent() 
{
    if (Kernel::MAJOR_VERSION > 2) {
        return EntityType::class;
    } else {
        return 'entity';
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work for two reasons: The installed versions of the HttpKernel component and the Form component do not have to be the same. Secondly, the first case (which will only be used with Symfony 3 with your code) should also be used with Symfony 2.8 to not get deprecation warnings.